# check palindrome by recursion in c

Tags: c, recursion, palindrome

I have to check if a number is palindrome or not using recursion..i am using the following function but i am confused because whenever i use a **while loop** in place of **if** statement an infinite loop is generated!

Why is the while loop not working properly?

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int Check_Pal(int);
int main()
{
    int i,sum,n;
    printf("enter no");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    sum=Check_Pal(n);
    if(sum==n)
    {
        printf("palindrome");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("not a palindrome");
    }
    return 0;
}
int Check_Pal(int k)
{
    int r;
    static int sum=0;
    while(k!=0)//if i use an if its fine but while loop does not work 
    {
        r=k%10;
        sum = sum*10+r;
        Check_Pal(k/10);    
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: How do you expect us to tell you why it's not working if you don't show what you wrote?

Comment: Share the code with while loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a `while` loop in your code, because the recursive call to the function `Check_Pal()` gives the effect of a while loop.

Consider your code given below,

```
while(k!=0)
{
    r=k%10;
    sum = sum*10+r;
    Check_Pal(k/10);    
    ^
    |__ Here you are discarding the value returned by "int Check_Pal()"
}
```

Also to get proper results it might be better to declare the variable `sum` as global.

Try something like this,

```
int sum=0;

void Check_Pal(int k)
{
    int r;
    if(k!=0)
    {
        r=k%10;
        sum = sum*10+r;
        Check_Pal(k/10);    
    }
}

int main()
{
  int n;
  printf("enter no");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  Check_Pal(n);
  if(sum==n)
  {
      printf("\npalindrome");
  }
  else
  {
      printf("\nnot a palindrome");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See, In your code k is not changed when you do `Check_Pal(k/10)` only the `k/10` value will be assigned to `k` in the recursive call but not to the current local variable `k`. However you do not even need to use a while loop here.
So, when you give a positive non-zero value expression in `while` always evaluates to true on first level of recursion with non-zero `k`, therefore infinite loop is occured.
So, `k` in the first call never gets zero... if non-zero input is given

```
int Check_Pal(int k)
{
    int r;
    static int sum=0;
    while(k!=0)//this always evaluates to true on first level of recursion with non-zero k 
    {
        r=k%10;
        sum = sum*10+r;
        Check_Pal(k/10);//value is assigned to k in recursive call not to the current k
    }
    return sum;
}
```

All the best...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses a recursion but doesn't need a global variable

```
bool checkpal(int k) {
    int r = k % 10, power_of_10=1;
    while (10 * power_of_10 < k) power_of_10 *= 10;
    if (k / power_of_10 != r) return false;
    if (power_of_10 == 1) return true;
    int next_k = (k - r * power_of_10) / 10;
    return (power_of_10 == 1000 && next_k < 11 ? next_k == 0 : checkpal(next_k));
}
```

Update: Just realised that this is imperfect. The test `power_of_10 == 1000 && next_k < 11` in the last line only takes care of one type of case where removing the most significant digit results in a next_k with a leading zero. No doubt this could be fixed, but right now I don't have the time.

Answer (score 0):

In the "while" loop you haven't changed k, the statement "k != 0" is always true. Therefore you will loop infinitely.